# Column NameStudent repeats the first element from a database table in a column dataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

i created a separate class ListStudents to output the name of students but only 1 name is repeated

```
class ListStudents : ObservableCollection<Student>
    {
        public static TitleStudentEntities DataStudent { get; set; }
        public ListStudents()
        {
            {
                var student = PageAttendance.DataStudent.Students;
                var queryStudent = student.OrderBy(x => x.name);
                foreach (Student emp in queryStudent)
                {
                    this.Add(emp);

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Class PageAttendace. here I am displaying the number of hours missed by students.

```
public partial class PageAttendance : Page
    {
        public static TitleStudentEntities DataAttendance { get; set; }
       public static TitleStudentEntities DataStudent { get; set; }
        ObservableCollection<Attendance> ListAttendance;
        ObservableCollection<Student> ListStudent;

        public PageAttendance()
        {
            DataAttendance = new TitleStudentEntities();
           DataStudent = new TitleStudentEntities(); 
            InitializeComponent();
            ListAttendance = new ObservableCollection<Attendance>();
            ListStudent = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var attendance = DataAttendance.Attendances;
            var queryAttendance = attendance.OrderBy(x => x.skippedHours);
            foreach (Attendance emp in queryAttendance)
            {
                ListAttendance.Add(emp);

            }
            DataGridAttendance.ItemsSource = ListAttendance;
        }
      

    }
    
}
```

this is how the column binding in xaml.

```
<DataGridTextColumn   Header="nameStudent"  Binding="{Binding name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Source={StaticResource listStudents1}}"   Width="200"/>
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `ListAttendance.Add (emp);`.
And after stopping execution, check the values of the `emp` properties.

Comment: And keep in mind, the ListStudents class in your implementation is meaningless.
Better make a normal Model that just returns a list of students.
And sorting is better done in the view itself using the CollectionViewSource class.